# the file is empty in git

Tags: git, github

Recently, I confuse with peculiar problem about Git. I
have a repository named ***Test***. there are two branch named ***master*** and ***A***. there is both file ***main.cpp*** in branch ***master*** and ***A*** . there are some test code in the main.cpp. for example,

```
int main()
{
    auto a{3};
}
```

it's same in ***master*** and ***A***

I clone this repository,
After clone, I switch to branch A by command ***git checkout A***. after then, I attempt to make some changes to main.cpp in ***branch A***. for example,

```
int main()
{
    auto a{3};
    auto b{4};
}
```

as canonical way, I push this changes to code in term of command ***git add*** ,***git commit*** and ***git push*** . It seems that everything is well in ***branch A*** after a series of operation.

after that, I checkout master. The peculiar phenomenon is happend. The main.cpp in master get empty. it's means that the code in main.cpp will be clear. Why this happened. I cannot understand. I must use command ***git reset --hard*** if the file to be restore I want

Comment: you can check the logs using [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

Comment: What OS and version of Git are you using?  Is this repository in a directory controlled by a cloud-syncing service like DropBox?  Are you using a non-default antivirus or firewall or any tool that intercepts file operations, like a corporate security tool?

Comment: What do `git status` and `git diff` print before and after switching branches? Which exact command(s) are you running? Is your _local_ master different from `origin/master` in your repo?

Comment: Your last sentences confuses me as well. `reset --hard` is not used to restore a file, but it is used to reset a tree (and move the current branch to a different commit). Can you provide the output of `git rev-list master`, `git rev-list origin/master`, and `git rev-list branchA`? (possibly `git log --oneline --decorate --graph master...branchA` if the number of commits is small enough)

Comment: Are you sure the file in `master` is not empty?

Comment: suspect a misuse of the commands. Your question is not that clear. Do you mean that the main.cpp is totally "empty" like le file is empty or that the line you just added disapeard ?
Because for the changes to apply on master you need to merge the branch A to master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may be caused by my specifical environment. These operations I mentioned above is not reproduce in other PC. Hence, it could be considered as resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).